someone else could get/have gotten in
It's early morning. Parents have discovered that their daughter forgot her keys at home when she left for work. Both of them need to leave because they have a flight in three hours. They decide to lock the door to prevent anyone from entering and stealing something. After arriving at the airport, the mother says to the father: "We shouldn't have locked the door. When she returns from work, she won't be able to get in and will be upset." The father replies to the mother:
1. But if we hadn't locked the door, someone else could have gotten in long before she did, and then we all would have been upset. Don't worry! She'll stay with her boyfriend until we return.
2. But if we hadn't locked the door, someone else could get in long before she does, and then we would all be upset. Don't worry! She'll stay with her boyfriend until we return.
If at the time of speaking the daughter is still at work, which version should be used? I'm wondering about the bolded tenses. Thank you.


But if we hadn't locked the door, someone else could have gotten in long before she did, and then we all would have been upset. Don't worry! She'll stay with her boyfriend until we return.

RIGHT. The past conditional works fine there.
Now the one below is fine:
2. But if we don't lock the door, someone else could get in long before she does, and then we would all be upset. Don't worry! She'll stay with her boyfriend until we return.
Now, it's a conditional in the simple present.

I think Lambie's reply is correct, and that version #1 should be used in the context given. I don't understand why this reply was downvoted. Does anyone agree with Lambie?

@prof1589 Because the obvious grammar does not please everyone.

As the daughter is still at work at the time of speaking, example (1) is ruled out because of did.  As for example (2), we should use didn’t lock because the moment of speaking is set in the present:

2a. But if we [didn't lock] the door, someone else could get in long before she does, and then we would all be upset.

Example (1) would work in a conversation after the daughter’s return.  In response to the wife’s query why he locked the door, the husband could explain:


But if we hadn't locked the door, someone else could have gotten in long before she did, and then we all would have been upset.



Version #2a is a correct sentence, but it doesn't fit the context. "If we didn't lock the door..." would be appropriate if they were just about to leave and hadn't yet locked the door, not when the door is locked and they're already at the airport. Your version #1 would work in the situation you describe, but that's not the context I have provided.

(1) Before the locking, nothing has happened.  Things are in the present; we use don’t.  (2) After the locking, only this activity is past; we use didn’t to describe it but not hadn’t.  (3) After the daughter’s return, we have one more past event.  We use hadn’t to describe the older one.
